How can I add a functioning Control key to my keyboard layout?
I'm working on adding my keyboard layout to /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols. So far it's going good, but I am having trouble with adding Control and Shift keys.
    key <AC03>  {[ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,   Shift_L  ]};
    key <AC04>  {[ NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol, Control_L  ]};

Shift and Control should activate when ISO_Level5_Shift key (CapsLock in my case) is held. And I do see them being activated with xev. The problem is, when normal keys (keyboard's standard Control and Shift) are activated I see 2 messages in the console: one when I begin to hold it and one when I release it.
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25675018, (169,156), root:(169,225),
    state 0x4000, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25675105, (169,156), root:(169,225),
    state 0x4001, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

But when I hold my Control or Shift, it behaves as any normal alphanumerical key
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25848695, (125,-27), root:(275,192),
    state 0x4020, keycode 40 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25850017, (125,-27), root:(275,192),
    state 0x4021, keycode 40 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25850303, (125,-27), root:(275,192),
    state 0x4020, keycode 40 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 50
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 25851266, (125,-27), root:(275,192),
    state 0x4021, keycode 40 (keysym 0x0, NoSymbol), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

And the cycle goes on until I release the key.
KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 26172617, (401,174), root:(717,413),
    state 0x4020, keycode 41 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 26172647, (401,174), root:(717,413),
    state 0x4020, keycode 41 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 26172647, (401,174), root:(717,413),
    state 0x4020, keycode 41 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 38, synthetic NO, window 0x3400001,
    root 0x609, subw 0x0, time 26172678, (401,174), root:(717,413),
    state 0x4020, keycode 41 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 37
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

Constantly being pressed and released, never stay in held position. How can I achieve them being held?
Update: I managed to get L_Shift working by adding one more instance of every character after level5
    key <AD08>  {[          NoSymbol,         NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,     Up  ]};
VVV
    key <AD08>  {[          NoSymbol,         NoSymbol, NoSymbol, NoSymbol,     Up,     Up  ]};
Control is the only problem left.
